# How to fix broken secondary AD server?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012

My Secondary Active Directory server has gone dead, and I am installing its replacement now. Everything will be the same, computer name, IP, everything.

The new server is running now, and ADDS installed, but I am hesitating to promote this new server to ADDS, since I am afraid to disturb the current running server. My question is, how do I replace the old domain controller? Should I just install ADDS, and promote it? Or should I do a cleanup? What is the best practice to reinstall ADDS?

I have no backup of this secondary server, since it was dead only within 2 days after operational. Perhaps hardware defect, malfunction or something else.

Thank you.

Comment: As I understand, the link mentioned, involves demoting a DC. My current hardware is unoperational, thus I cannot demote my old DC. I was asking, if I should do something else in demoting a DC step if I replace it with same name and IP. Or should I just skip it and continue the next step.

Comment: IP addresses are irrelevant to active directory, if you haven't removed the stale controller objects I'd recommend a new hostname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should manually remove the old domain controller from the active directory and then install the new one.

---

First check the fsmo roles - run in an elevated cmd shell

```
netdom query fsmo
```

And move fsmo roles which are on the failed DC to the running DC

---

Then remove the failed DC from the active directory:

> **Step 1: Cleaning up metadata via Active Directory Users and Computers**
>
> 1. Log in to DC server as Domain/Enterprise administrator and navigate to Server Manager > Tools > Active Directory Users and Computers
> 2. Expand the Domain > Domain Controllers
> 3. Right click on the DC server that need to remove manually and click delete
> 4. In next dialog box, click yes to confirmmeta3
> 5. n next dialog box, select This Domain Controller is permanently offline and can no longer be demoted using the Active Directory Domain Services Installation Wizard (DCPROMO) and click Delete
> 6. If the domain controller is global catalog server, in next window click yes to continue with deletion
> 7. If the domain controller holds any FSMO roles in next window, click ok to move them to the domain controller which is available
>
> **Step 2: Cleaning up the DC server instance from the Active Directory Sites and Services**
>
> 1. Go to Server manager > Tools > Active Directory Sites and Services
> 2. Expand the Sites and go to the server which need to remove
> 3. Right click and click Deletemeta5
> 4. In next window click yes to confirmmeta6
>
> **Step 3: Clean up metadata using ntdsutil**
>
> 1. Right Click on Start > Command Prompt (admin)
> 2. Type ntdsutil and entermeta7
> 3. Then metadata cleanupmeta8
> 4. Next type remove selected server , replace  with DC server to removemeta9
> 5. In warning window click yes to proceed
> 6. Execute quit command twice

quoted from: [Step-By-Step: Removing A Domain Controller Server Manually](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2016/02/17/step-by-step-removing-a-domain-controller-server-manually/)

Comment: Ok. So I have to remove it first before promoting the new server. Thank you.